# How to pass value to external javascript file using asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm doing validation in asp.net through an external javascript file. How can I pass the value to the function which is in the external javascript file?

my asp code is:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtInput"></asp:TextBox> 
<asp:Button runat="server" 
    OnClientClick="javascript:phonenumber(document.getElementByID('<%txtInput.text %>'))" 
    Text="Click"/>
```

When I click this button it's supposed to show an alert message, but it didn't. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

My Javascript code is:

```
function phonenumber(inputtxt)  
{  
    var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;  
    if(inputtxt.value.match(phoneno))  
    {  
        return true;  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        alert("Not a valid Phone Number");  
        return false;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Look at the JavaScript console. What errors do you get? (You have an obvious typo that it should alert you to)

Comment: Also, since your using asp.net why not used the regex validator?  all asp validation is handled clientside by default (`EnableClientScript="True"`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here.  First remember that the `<%= txtInput.text %>` is going to produce an output that looks like `javascript:phonenumber()` because the text box presumably has no value when the page is rendered.  Even if the user changes the textbox, it wont be reflected in that function call.

Second, you don't need the `javascript:` part.  And as previously mentioned, it's case sensitive. Third, the JavaScript code for your regex is missing some parenthesis.

Try something like this:

function ValidatePhone(element) {
            var el = document.getElementById(element);

```
        var phoneno = "/^\d{10}$/";
        if (el.value.match(phoneno)) {
            alert("Valid");
            return true;
        } else {
            alert("Not a valid Phone Number");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

```
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtInput" ClientIDMode="Static" />
        <asp:Button runat="server" OnClientClick="ValidatePhone('txtInput');" Text="Test" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Note: I didn't test your regex function.

Comment: It allows you to control whether the ASP.NET compiler assigns the name or if you do.  It's useful in situations like this, but I try not to use it too frequently because if you rename elements you have to remember to update them in multiple places in the code. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

another option: set the textbox `ClientIDMode` to `Static` and just reference the input field by ID as txtInput, this way you can avoid the name mangling and make your input fields more JS friendly such that this:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtInput" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox> 
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClientClick="phonenumber()" Text="Click"/>
```

is rendered as: *(note the id on the text input)*

```
<input name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$txtInput" type="text" id="txtInput">
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$Button1" value="Click" onclick="phonenumber();" id="MainContent_Button1">
```

Also note that the button is rendered as a submit type, which will force a postback anyway.
yiou may just want to use a plain `<button>` html tag with a plain `onclick='phonenumber()'` to avoid postback because even if you choose to render the `<asp:Button>` with attribute `UseSubmitBehavior="False"` it will still inject a postback after your `OnClientClick` code.

JS:

```
function phonenumber()  
{  
    var phoneNumText = document.getElementById('txtInput');
    var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;  
    if(phoneNumText.value.match(phoneno))  
        return true;  
    else  
    {  
        alert("Not a valid Phone Number");  
        return false;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Yes when i m using plain button and a textbox it works even when passing the argument....but when it comes to asp control ..nothing happens

Comment: You can stop the postback by adding `CausesValidation=False` in addition to the `UseSubmitBehavior`

Comment: @Abhay: that's due to the `asp:Button` rendering as a submit type, the postback is stomping the JS call.  You need to use an asp button type that does not render to a submit type button. The asp button controls are closely tied to the asp.net validation controls and they render a lot of their own javascript.  It gets very complicated very quickly when you try to weave your own validation into the mix, I've found it best to either use the built in ASP validation, or use basic HTML and avoid ASP.NET validation completely. You can still trigger postbacks from JS via `__doPostBack();`